# Reading a process memory

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to read memory from a process (calc.exe). But I'm hitting "Could not read memory" message. Where is my mistake?

```
int main() {
    HWND handle = FindWindow(0, TEXT("Calculadora"));
    if (!handle) {
        msg("Could not find window");
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD id;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &id);
    HANDLE proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, id);
    if (!proc) {
        msg("Could not open process");
        return 0;
    }

    char buffer[128];
    if (ReadProcessMemory(proc, 0, &buffer, 128, NULL)) {
        msg("yes!!");
    }
    else {
        msg("Could not read memory");
    }

    CloseHandle(proc);
}
```

Comment: Do you have read-access-privilage?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık i'm noob, sorry. Can you be clearer? How can i get such privilages?

Comment: i am noob too but the name should be something like PROC_HANDLE = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PROC_ID);

Comment: Why are you trying to read memory from Calc? Why not just use accessibility to read the calculation result?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Why would you want `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` just to call `ReadProcessMemory`. The documentation is clear in stating that is not needed.

Comment: @RaymondChen its just a test. :P

Comment: @RaymondChen Presumably Calc is simply a test program. Could equally be Notepad.

Comment: Same thing works for Notepad. To read text from Notepad, use the accessibility interface. Whatever program you want, use the accessibility or automation interface. That's what it's for. Memory addresses are subject to change at any time without warning. (ASLR makes sure of that.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Indeed that is so. But, there are indeed valid uses for `ReadProcessMemory`. And if one was attempting to learn how to use that API, one would presumably pick on something like Calc or Notepad as the guinea pig.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It would be much better to learn how to use the API in the manner it was intended. Write two programs: The first program allocates some memory and sends the address to the second program, which then tries to read it. Note that `ReadProcessMemory` is not a recommended IPC mechanism, however, since it has poor security granularity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are attempting to read address 0 in the target process. That will always fail. You need to read from an address which is meaningful in the virtual address space of the target process.

Note that in order to call `ReadProcessMemory` you only need `PROCESS_VM_READ`. That's not the problem here, but I thought I would point it out for sake of completeness.

Comment: Oh.. i thought that meant local address of the process... so how can i get the exactly start address of the process? (its length too).

Comment: There's not really any such thing. The process could be using  addresses scattered all over the address space. In any case, that's really a different question. This question is answered.

Comment: How come? how will i read memory from the process if i cannot know its start? :O

Comment: As I said, that's a different problem. I've no idea even what you are trying to do. You could ask another question along those lines, specifying some details about what you are trying to read. But this question asked why the code failed, and I answered that.

Comment: Should I add a second question on the original one, then?

Comment: No, you should ask an entirely new question. The rules here are that you ask one question per post. This question is done. Your new question should be just that, a new question.

Comment: Ok, I will presume your answer is right then, since i can't test if it works yet.

Comment: if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215719/reading-the-start-address-and-length-of-a-process